# How do I connect Arduino nano with QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB Serial Adaptor to OpenWrt?

Tags: arduino, openwrt

When I connect the USB interface from my arduino nano to my openwrt router then the command `lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
```

But I do not get a new serial device in `/dev/tty*`

I have `kmod-usb-serial` installed.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189896/testing-if-hl-340-works/361199

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting this in case it is useful to others.  The answer turns out to be that I needed the `kmod-usb-serial-ch341` kernel package:

```
opkg install kmod-usb-serial-ch341
```

The HL-340 is a CH 340 compatible device.

Once the ch341 driver is installed the nano appears as `/dev/ttyUSB0` and defaults to 115200 baud.  From `dmesg`

```
[   20.000000] usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
[   20.000000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
[   20.010000] ch341 1-1.2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[   20.040000] usb 1-1.2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```